# binary search pointers dynamic memory allocation recursion

Tags: c, pointers, recursion, binary-search, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm doing an implementation of binary search with pointers and dynamic memory allocation. I first sort the list of elements and then I perform the search. The sorting part works perfectly but my search isn't working properly. I know that the algorithm is correct but I have no idea how to go about the syntax.Could someone help me out?? PS This is my first question on stack overflow, BTW. :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int binary_search(int x,int start,int end, int *array)
{
   int q;
   q=(start+end)/2;
   if(x==*(array+q))
   {
      return q;
   }
   else if (x>*(array+q))
   {
      binary_search(x,q+1,end,array);
   }

   else if (x<*(array+q))
   {
      binary_search(x,start,q-1,array);
   }

   else if(start>=end)
      return -1;
}

int main()
{
   int n,*a,tmp,i,j,search,pos;
   printf("Enter n");
   scanf("%d",&n);
   a=malloc(sizeof(int)*n);

   for(i=0;i<n;i++)
   {
      scanf("%d",&tmp);
      *(a+i)=tmp;
   }

   for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
   {
      for(j=0;j<n-1;j++)
      {
         if(*(a+j)>*(a+j+1))
         {
            tmp=*(a+j);
            *(a+j)=*(a+j+1);
            *(a+j+1)=tmp;
         }
      }
   }

   printf("Sorted elements are\n");
   for(i=0;i<n;i++)
   {
      printf(" %d",*(a+i));
   }

   printf("Enter element to search\n");
   scanf("%d",&search);
   pos=binary_search(search,0,n-1,&a);
   printf("\nThe element is located at position %d",pos);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: "*search isn't working properly* what exactly is not working.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, `*(array+q)` is same as `array[q]`.

Secondly, you should do some research before posting a question.
http://www.cquestions.com/2008/01/c-program-for-binary-search-through.html

In case the number to be searched does not exist, it got in an infinite loop.
This should fix it.

```
int binary_search(int x,int start,int end, int *a)
{
    int q;
    if(start>end)
        return -1;
    q=(start+end)/2;
    if(x==*(a+q))
    {
        return q;
    }
    else if (x>*(a+q))
    {
        return binary_search(x,q+1,end,a);
    }

    else if (x<*(a+q))
    {
        return binary_search(x,start,q-1,a);
    }

}
```

Comment: Allthough basically correct, I think it should be `if(start > end)`.

Comment: Yes it should be. Fixed it

Answer (score 2):

In addition to above answers -

```
int binary_search(int x,int start,int end, int *array)
                                                ^integer pointer
```

But in `main` you are passing it an `int **` type-

```
pos=binary_search(search,0,n-1,&a);
                               ^a is already an integer pointer
```

Compiler will issue a warning.
Just pass `a` in this. And also you forgot to `free` `a` as you have allocated memory to it using `malloc`.

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to add `return` in the recursive calls. As a consequence, the function falls off the end without a proper return value.

Also, the check `if(start>=end)` needs to be performed at the very top. Otherwise, you will see infinite recursion when `x` is not in `array`.

Updated:

```
int binary_search(int x,int start,int end, int *array)
{
   int q;

   if(start>=end)
      return -1;

   q=(start+end)/2;

   if(x==*(array+q))
   {
      return q;
   }
   else if (x>*(array+q))
   {
      // Add return
      return binary_search(x,q+1,end,array);
   }

   // There is no need to do any further checks.
   return binary_search(x,start,q-1,array);
}
```

Comment: To me it seems `else if(start>=end)` is never reached as all possible case for `x` had been covered before, thus the missing final `return` also would never be readched, thus its sole purpose would be to silence the compiler.

Comment: @alk It would be eventually reached! If an element is  not found.

Comment: No, we have three return statements, one for `x==`, one for `x<` and one for `x>`. One of those matches in any case.

Comment: @alk It eventually will if not found. This is due to the fact that we adjust 'start' and 'end' if *(a+q) is > than or less than x, thus leading to start>=end
http://www.csit.parkland.edu/~mbrandyberry/CS1Java/Lessons/Lesson27/BinarySearch.htm

Comment: What else can `x` be then equal, less or more `*(array+q)`??? (refering to the code **you** show)